# Repita o fundo animado

Tags: java, android, xml

Eu fiz um aplicativo com um fundo animado, aqui está o código:

Layout principal:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >
...
```

A lista de animação:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/matrix_39" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/matrix_38" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/matrix_37" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/matrix_36" android:duration="100" />
...
```

A implementação java:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    LinearLayout bck;
    AnimationDrawable ad;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bck = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
        bck.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_animation);
        ad = (AnimationDrawable) bck.getBackground();
        ad.start();
}
```

Bem, ele funciona muito bem como pano de fundo animado de tela cheia, mas eu gostaria de repetir a imagem animada de fundo. Há um caminho?

Answer (score 1):

Se percebi bem a sua pergunta o que você tem de fazer é adicionar `ad.setOneShot(false)` antes de fazer `ad.start()`.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    LinearLayout bck;
    AnimationDrawable ad;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bck = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
        bck.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progress_animation);
        ad = (AnimationDrawable) bck.getBackground();
        ad.setOneShot(false);
        ad.start();
}
```

Outra coisa que eu li na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#start%28%29) é que `start()` não deve ser feito no método onCreate da `Activity` mas sim em `onWindowFocusChanged`